# Login to website perform db query inside the website based on an individual identification number and scrape results out into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, authentication, search

I have 10 unique individual ids. These are the steps I want to automize:

1. Login into website with login and password
2. Take first unique id from a list(dataframe) insert that id into an existing search box INSIDE the website and hit enter
3. If I have data returned I want to extract that returned data from the website and save it somehow preferably in a new dataframe
4. Next go to next unique id and do the same -insert it in the existing search box INSIDE the website...- basically iterate over the entire list of 10 ids
5. Once I have extracted the data for all 10 unique ids I want to search and sort and group any of the returned data on particular keywords(this I think I got)

Can 1-4 be done using straight python and python libs?

Not sure where to even begin

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Honestly if you can get away with it, use HTTP requests (so either pip install requests) or use urllib from the standard library.  Open up the network tab of the developer console in the browser you're using and see what requests are being sent with the data you're submitting to the site.  These will form the basis of the requests you'll be needing to send.

Comment: Thank you mike and manwithfewneeds for the feedback . I've put this project on the backburner for now as other more interesting projects just came up.